# How to extract last occurrence of a particular 'string' from a vector

Tags: r, string, find-occurrences

I have a vector of several binary numbers stored in it.  Since these are already filtered, it is also known that all are greater than 0.

```
v <- c(1, 10, 11, 110, 10000, 101000, 100100000, 100001)
```

Now I want a `result_vector` (vector because input vector is a column in a data frame) giving me position/location of last occurrence of `1` in the vector `v`.  I am trying `stringr::str_locate(as.Charachter(v), "1")[,2]` but it gives me ending position of first occurence of this vector.  `stringr::str_locate_all` gives result in a list instead therefore not useful in the context.  Moreover, I want this position counted from backwards.  However, if I can extract location from left that can be converted to reverse by substracting from `nchar(as.Charachter(v))`. Please guide me how can I proceed to get a result like

```
result_vector = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 1)
```

Comment: do you need to find position of `1` in each element of the vector? your input vector has 8 elements but your result has 7

Comment: Yes @VasilyA thanks for pointing out the error.  I have corrected the desired_output, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result_vector <- nchar(v) - sapply(stringr::str_locate_all(as.character(v), "1"), max) + 1
```

Answer (score 3):

One `stringi` option could be:

```
stri_locate_first(stri_reverse(v), fixed = "1")[, 1]

[1] 1 2 1 2 5 4 6 1
```

Answer (score 1):

As the digits are either 1 or 0, your question is logically equivalent to counting the number trailing zeros.

```
result_vector <- nchar(x) - nchar(trimws(x, "right", "0")) + 1L
```